# Nvidia Jetson Nano on Ubuntu 18.04 completes docker run with "exec format error"

Tags: image, docker, nvidia-jetson

NVidia Jetson Nano on Ubuntu 18.04 completes docker run with `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`, but some images run completely fine.

```
organic@jetson:~$ docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 django
Unable to find image 'django:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/django
75a822cd7888: Pull complete
e4665cede9d1: Pull complete
202a45aa091c: Pull complete
7799136eb561: Pull complete
7a7f9ca3fd40: Pull complete
412f2d081014: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:5bfd3f442952463f5bc97188b7f43cfcd6c2f631a017ee2a6fca3cb8992501e8
Status: Downloaded newer image for django:latest
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

organic@jetson:~$ docker pull nginx:latest
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
Digest: sha256:50cf965a6e08ec5784009d0fccb380fc479826b6e0e65684d9879170a9df8566
Status: Image is up to date for nginx:latest
docker.io/library/nginx:latest

organic@jetson:~$ docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
be6e184261a6: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4fe721ccc2e8dc7362278a29dc660d833570ec2682f4e4194f4ee23e415e1064
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
docker.io/library/hello-world:latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `docker run` command pulls the `django` image just fine, but the running part fails.

The `Django:latest` docker image, is a `x86-64` only image. But as you are on a Jetson Nano (Arm architecture), you should find (or build) `arm64` compatible docker images and not `x86-64`.

The other two commands in your example that are completed without the same error, are only doing the pulling part. But they will most likely still run just fine as they are both `Arm64` compatible.

You can find the tags under the images on the [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/django).

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate. Oh, that's right I haven't looked to Docker image architecture in a first-place as I should. Anyway, when I'm navigating to the Tags search it can't find anything for the Arm64, just drops off "No tags found
This repository doesn't have any tags that have "arm64" in their names."

Comment: Try and search the entire DockerHub for "Django" and then select "arm64" architecture on the left side to only show arm64 compatible django images. There are a few unofficial docker images to download if you want. Otherwise you can try and build your own image with the things you need.